# Excel VBA attach multiple files from a cell which has file path

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have code to create auto email based on the values in a table created in Excel. The code attaches only 1 file from cell value. If there are more than 1 files either in same cell or next column, I am sort of lost on how to achieve this being a novice in VBA field. Appreciate if anyone can help.

Below is my code:-

```
 Sub SendEmailWithAttachmentAndBody()

'Created by Mirat for ****.
'This code will autocreate emails along relevant attachents. User needs to create a master data file to include following fields in respective columns.
'To = Column A.
'CC = Column B.
'Bcc = Column C.
'Subject = Column D.
'Body = Column E.
'Attachment = Column F.
'Only 1 file can be attached for now.

Dim OlAPP As Outlook.Application
Dim OlMail As Outlook.MailItem

For i = 2 To Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set OlAPP = New Outlook.Application
    Set OlMail = OlAPP.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    MailAttachment = Application.Cells(i, 6).Value

    With OlMail
    .Display
    End With
        Signature = OlMail.Body

    With OlMail
    .To = Cells(i, 1).Value
    .CC = Cells(i, 2).Value
    .BCC = Cells(i, 3)
    .Subject = Cells(i, 4).Value
    .HTMLBody = Cells(i, 5).Value & "<br>" & .HTMLBody
    .Attachments.Add MailAttachment

    .Display

    End With

    Set OlMail = Nothing
    Set OlAPP = Nothing
Next


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your questions, I make the assumption that the attachments in column F are stored as a comma separated string.

With that in mind I would make MailAttachment a variant variable and do the following:

```
MailAttachment = Split (Application.Cells(i, 6).Value, ",")
```

Then later in the code I would loop through this array and attach each file.

```
For each item in MailAttachment
.Attachments.Add item
Next
```

That should do the trick.